# Unable to focus on a Mat card using viewchildren Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to focus on a specific card from a list of mat cards

But I keep getting error

> Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined

[Stackblitz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gu5kpe?file=app/card-overview-example.html)

Should add a gold outline on click of button

```
import { Component, OnInit, QueryList, ElementRef, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';

/**
 * @title Basic cards
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'card-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'card-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['card-overview-example.css'],
})
export class CardOverviewExample implements OnInit {

  comments: number[];
  @ViewChildren("commentCard") commentCardList: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.comments = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
  }

  focus() {
    const elementRef = this.commentCardList.find((item, index) => index === 4);
    elementRef.nativeElement.focus();
//this.commentCardList[4].nativeElement.focus();

  }

}
```

Comment: are you using template reference or Id for your comment card?

Comment: @AjayReddy check stackblitz i put wrong link before

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, you have to assign view id to show which elements you want to query

```
<mat-card #commentCard *ngFor="let comment of comments" tabindex="0">Comment {{comment}}</mat-card>
```

Next: `MatCard` has not `nativeElement` so you have to fetch element reference

```
@ViewChildren("commentCard", { read: ElementRef })
```

And you are done

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gu5kpe-bbsmbu?file=app%2Fcard-overview-example.ts

Comment: I think it came with angular2 but idk for sure as i started with 4 :)

Answer (score 1):

1. The "commentCard" in `@ViewChildren("commentCard")` should reference something, so you need to put either a component/directive type or a template variable. A template variable means that you add `#name` in a html-tag, like this:

   `<mat-card #commentCard *ngFor="let comment of comments" tabindex="0">Comment {{comment}}</mat-card>`
2. You also need to tell `@ViewChildren` that you want to get the DOM element and not the Angular component, like this `@ViewChildren("commentCard", { read: ElementRef }) commentCardList: QueryList<ElementRef>;`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gu5kpe-dqua65?file=app%2Fcard-overview-example.ts